# how to I rename a shape in Powerpoint after pasting from excel using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, rename, shapes

I am working on a macro from excel VBA that copies charts and text boxes into a powerpoint presentation. When I copy the chart over it keeps its name that I had assigned it in excel but the text gets placed into a rectangle shape with a random name. 
I can I rename the text box immediately after pasting?

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: In addition to using the [edit] link to add the code you already have, please also include a screen shot showing the result of the code, indicating the "rectangle shape". Based on my experience, however, you might try renaming these text box shapes with meaningful names before copying and pasting. Office tends to discard / replace the default names it uses. Especially if they might conflict with Shapes in the target document.

Comment: Another problem is when Office does not change a pasted shape's name even if it's already in use in the target context, so you have duplicate names.

Comment: When I paste or create shapes (and charts) from Excel to PowerPoint, I make note of the new shape, and if relevant, I give it a new name.